# Average distance between remaining un-hit targets as targets are progressively hit

Tags: probability-distributions

Consider targets arranged in a regularly spaced array across a near-infinite X-Y plane (area of plane is large relative to area of a target).
   Each target is initially a unit distance from adjacent targets.

Targets exist initially as open.
Targets progressively close.
The fraction of closed targets is measurable, from 1 (all open) to 0 (all closed).

How can I model the average distance, D, separating an open target to the nearest open target as a function of the progressive fraction, f, of closed targets.

An approximation:
Df = D/f

My question was tagged as 'biology' and 'unclear';  I am posting here to ask for the vocabulary to properly pose my question.  I am confident the solution exists.

Biology:
I am modelling photochemical properties of phytoplankton.
Phytoplankton have reaction centres embedded in planar membranes.
Photons hit reaction centres and the reaction centres are 'closed', or busy, for a period (~1 ms) until they can process another photon.

From the perspective of an individual reaction centre we can model the probability of closure as a poisson target function versus incident photons per unit area.

I need to estimate the average distance between open reaction centres, as a function of the fraction of closed reaction centres.

Geometrically I can approximate the system as an infinite array of points, with unit spacing between points.
When all reaction centres are open, average distance between points = 1.
Since all reaction centres are open, average distance between open reactions centres = 1.

When all reaction centres are closed (as happens under excess light), average distance between open reaction centres is infinite.

But what is the shape of the curve in between?
I can readily measure the fraction of closed reaction centres, and I need to convert that to an average distance between open reaction centres.

If someone can point me towards the correct vocabulary to ask the question, I would be grateful.

Comment: Isn´t it useful to know how many reaction centers are embedded in planar membrane ?

Comment: This is not even a math question. This is a biology question!

Comment: I have numbers for the actual physical spacing and numbers of the reaction centres, but to a first approximation they are evenly spaced, and the membrane surface is large relative to an individual reaction centre.  So I think it can be modelled as evenly spaced points in an infinite plane.

Comment: Just did an empirical model and found that average distance between reaction centres = 1/(fraction of closed reaction centres).